# Class Diagram Alternative for Qualified Association

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I am using PlantUML and it unfortunately does not support qualifiers on a class. I simply want to show in PlantUML that a `Task` has a qualified association to `User` through the `Task.userID` property.

[A link to quick explanation of Qualified Association](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS5JSH_9.1.0/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cqualassocend.html)

Here is a simple snippet of the two classes which can't be associated through a qualifier. However the square brackets around `userID` was a suggestion by someone, `[userID]`. Is this really the only way?

```
@startuml
Class Task {
   userID : int
} 

Class User {

}

Task "[userID]" --> "1" User
@enduml
```

Simply copy paste this snippet above to any PlantUML parser.

Is there an alternative way of denoting a qualified relationship?

I have also thought about stereotyping the `userID` property like so: `userID : int <<qualifier>>`. Any qualms or issues with this idea?

Comment: A qualifier is a qualifier. Why should one have alternative notations if one already exists?

Comment: Well one reason to have an alternative is the situation I'm in, hence why I asked. Would love if I could just use qualifiers but PlantUML seems to think they are not necessary and therefore a notation for qualifiers does not already exist.

Comment: You can't blame UML for tools not implementing the standard :-/ Eventually your need to "photoshop" you Plantuml results :-( Or you just switch to a tool that supports the standard.